# C Looping If Statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am working on a quiz with C, but I ran into a problem. Why is C looping the if statement "if (ans==true)"? I know this because the variable sum is a crazy number like 32767.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool askQuestion(char question[100],int answer){
    int userAns;

    printf("%s \n",question);
    scanf("%d",&userAns);

    if (userAns==answer){
      printf("Correct \n");
      return(true);
    }
    else{
      printf("Wrong \n");
      return (false);
    }
    printf("ERROR ERROR ERROR!");
}

int main(void)
{
  
    bool ans;
    int sum;

    ans = askQuestion("yoyoyo",10);
    if (ans==true){
      sum+=1;
    }



    printf("Your score was %d/5",sum);






    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: I didn't initialize the sum variable. My bad.**

Comment: `sum` is uninitialized.

Comment: Test the return value from `scanf("%d",&userAns);` in the case the user did not type in an integer. That input remains in the buffer

Comment: BTW - Where is the loop

Comment: @EdHeal I thought it was looping the if statement because sum was being increased. My bad.

Comment: Note: you also have undefined behaviour after the error is announced - the function does not return any value. This omission and the uninitialised variable are usually warned by the compiler.

Comment: Adding "-Wall" to your compilation process might be the best keystroke:benefit ratio you'll ever see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no looping involved, `sum` is uninitialized therefore it's value is **indeterminate**. Easy fix,

Initialize sum:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Also you might want to check the return value of `scanf()` in case an input error occurred,

```
if (scanf("%d", &userAns) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Scanf conversion error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); /* #include <stdlib.h> */
}
```

Comment: Perhaps an error message would be nice before the exit

Comment: Yes indeed, I've added @EdHeal

Answer (score 2):

Since `sum` is not initialized, `sum += 1` is undefined behavior.